# Classifying spikes as excitatory or inhibitory based on their shape

Tags: classification, pca, svm, neuroscience

[image]I have two classes of spike, namely, excitatory spikes and inhibitory spikes. In the figure you can see their shapes.

I want to classify my spikes based on these two shapes. The shape in the figure is very clean and in our real data the shape of the spikes have some noise. I want my classification algorithm chooses the class of each spike at least with 85-90% confidence. And if it can not choose with this much confidence then calls it noise.

Does anybody have any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: Pls post the figure.

Comment: Why did you put PCA and SVM tags here?

Comment: I was wondering if I can use any of these two methods for classification.

Comment: The spikes appear to have nearly identical *shapes*: they appear to differ only in their *scales.*  Is this the case, or can you characterize how the shapes are supposed to differ?  What can you say about the "noise" in your data?  How does it arise and--importantly--how is it correlated over time?

Comment: @Mina So judging from these examples, the only difference between the two spikes is in the timing of the trough and its tail. Is that typical? If that's the case, have you thought of using the time delta from peak to trough and the half-life of the tail decay as features for a binary classification?

Comment: @whuber Usually Inh spikes have faster falling time, meaning the time from the peak to trough and their full width half maximum is smaller than Ex spikes. However when I am using these two parameters, spikes are not separability well enough. I am assuming that one of the reason is that I have a lot of spikes which are from non of these two classes and I call them noise. Plus as I mentioned earlier this figure just show a schematic of Ex and In spikes. But real spikes are not this smooth. That's why I don't want to impose any predefined parameter for the classification.

Comment: @horaceT, I did peak to trough and  full width half maximum but it didn't work. What do you mean exactly by half-life of the tail decay?

Comment: +1 to @horaceT. This is a standard thing in electrophysiology, have you looked at how people do it in published papers? E.g.: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/260254454_fig2_A-classification-of-the-detected-spikes-The-right-panel-shows-the-classified-mean-spike With the current amount of information in the question, this is almost off-topic. A useful answer would *have* to be based on the good domain knowledge about what features of the spike waveforms are the most reliable. If you want this to be on-topic, consider e.g. showing your real data.

Comment: Or here https://www.researchgate.net/figure/278968841_fig1_Figure-S1-Classification-of-putative-inhibitory-INH-and-excitatory-EXC-neurons-based or Figure 1 here http://jn.physiology.org/content/108/10/2725 (cc to @horaceT)